# Como dar disable em um botão durante a requisição ajax com primefaces?

Tags: jquery, primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-5.2

Como dar disable em um botão durante a requisição ajax com primefaces usando o p:ajaxStatus.

Queria fazer isso de uma forma genérica, 
ex: todos os botões vão ser desativados durante a requisição ajax;

Answer (score 0):

Olha, eu faço algo parecido no meu TC, é diferente, mas a intenção é a mesma, Durante um ajax status, eu chamo um Dialog, com um Modal e além disso, ajusto na classe CSS um Z-Index Altíssimo. Não é exatamente do jeito que você quer, mas, o resultado é o mesmo: impedir que o usuário faça merda durante a requisição e processamento.